# Can't get MD5 checksum from security framework on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: objective-c, security, frameworks, nsdata

```
    NSString *curFourChanFilePath = [currentSubFile stringByAppendingPathComponent:curFourChanFile];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:curFourChanFilePath];

    CFErrorRef theError;

    SecTransformRef testTransform = SecDigestTransformCreate(kSecDigestMD5,0,&theError);

    CFDataRef theDataRef = (__bridge CFDataRef)imageData;

    SecTransformSetAttribute(testTransform, kSecTransformInputAttributeName, theDataRef, &theError);

    NSData *resultingData = (__bridge NSData *)(SecTransformExecute(testTransform, &theError));

    NSString *resultingString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultingData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",resultingString);

    [checksumMapTable setObject:resultingData forKey:curFourChanFile];
```

Here's the code I'm having issues with. This code is in a nested nested loop, and all the code works fine till it get to turning the data into an NSString. It seems to have trouble with UTF8. All the strings turn into (null), but the strange thing is, it isn't (null). When I change the encoding to UTF16 or UTF32, I get text. Not readable text, it's all garbled as you'd expect from using the wrong encoding, but it's clearly there, I just can't seem to get at it in what I thought was the proper encoding, UTF8. Any help would be appreciated. Just to reiterate, again, all the code seems to be working fine until this point. The Security framework is still a bit new to me.

Comment: What do you want to do with this string? The result of MD5 are bytes, not characters. That means that you have to be more precise concerning how you want to transform those bytes into characters.

Comment: Well, I tried following the example in Apple's documentation. I'm trying to get an MD5 checksum. I must be missing a step. Like I said, I'm completely new to the Security framework and manual checksumming in general. What I mean is that key that's outputted by things like OpenSSL's MD5 hash.

Comment: OpenSSL can output either raw bytes (by default), hexadecimal digits (-hex) or Base64 encoded (-base64) data. What is it you want?

Comment: Correction, to get raw bytes with OpenSSL you must pass `-binary` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I just answered my own question. using SecEncodeTransformCreate(NULL, NULL) and sending the data through that, I got the checksum. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Change your encoding to one that can decode *any* byte value. For example `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`. This should give you an output similar to `openssl md5 -binary`.

Not that the result will make much sense though…